# Isomorphisms between $V/U$, $U^0$ and $U^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I am working through Axler's LADR on my own and was wondering about what the "natural" isomorphisms between these spaces would be. If $V$ is finite-dimensional all 3 of these spaces have the same dimension ($dimV-dimU$) and hence should be isomorphic, correct?

An isomorphism between $U^\perp$ and $U^0$ seems the most natural: for each vector $u$ of $U^\perp$, $u\mapsto\varphi_u$, where $\varphi$ is an element of $U^0$ given by $\langle,u\rangle$. This mapping is obviously injective and surjective by the functional representation theorem (called the Riesz representation theorem in the book).

Next I tried coming up with one between $U^0$ and $V/U$ (and $U^\perp$ and $V/U$) in pretty much the exact way; for each $\varphi_v$ of $U^0$, $\varphi_v\mapsto v+U$, where a unique $v$ exists by the representation theorem ($\forall w\in U^\perp,w\mapsto w+U$). I seem to have managed to prove that both are isomorphisms. For the first one's injective part, suppose that the kernel is non-empty. Then there is a non-zero functional $\varphi_v$ which is mapped to the identity of $V/U$, i.e. $0+U$, hence $v\in U$. But since $\varphi_v(w)=\langle w,v\rangle\in U^0$ is $0$ for any $w\in U$, $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ and $v=0$, which is a contradiction. This felt a bit counter-intuitive to me, because at first I thought that there should be no reason why 2 different functionals shouldn't possibly map to the same affine subset, but the proof seems to be correct. For the other isomorphism proof of injection seems to be just as simple: suppose the kernel was non-empty, then $w\neq0$ maps to $0+U$ and hence $w\in U$. But if it were it would have to be orthogonal to every element of $U$, including itself, therefore $w=0$, which is a contradiction. For the surjective part of the 2nd one I thought it could be argued as follows: we know that $V=U\oplus U^\perp$, i.e. each vector $v$ can be uniquely represented as $u+u^\perp$. Then any element $v+U$ of $V/U$ can be written as $(u+u^\perp)+U$ or simply $u^\perp+U$. That is, every affine subset has a representative that is orthogonal to $U$ and hence a pre-image under this mapping. Argue surjectivity for the first one the same way, since $\varphi_{u^\perp}$ is in the annihilator.

My question I suppose would simply be whether my general line of reasoning is correct or not. I understand that all this is utterly trivial, I was just toying around by myself and was looking for validation for my direction of thinking. Apologies for the wall of text.

Comment: If their finite dimensional (same dimension), then they're isomorphic (just send a basis to a basis).  Halmos' _Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces_  is supposed to be good.  Maybe check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $V$ is a Hilbert space (e.g. a finite dimensional vector space with an inner product), $U\subseteq V$ is a sub-vector space and that by $U^0$ you denote the subspace of the dual of $V$ which evaluates to zero on $U$.

You have a canonical isomorphism $V\cong V^*$ given by sending $v$ to $\langle-,v\rangle$. This immediately implies that $U^\perp\cong U^0$ via this isomorphism (which makes the statement completely trivial).

The canonical isomorphism $V\cong U\oplus U^\perp$ implies the statement that $U^\perp\cong V/U$, as you noticed. However, a maybe more natural way to see this (that doesn't involve splitting $V$) is to consider the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow U\longrightarrow V\longrightarrow V/U\longrightarrow0\ .$$
Taking duals, we obtain the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow (V/U)^*\longrightarrow V^*\longrightarrow U^*\longrightarrow0\ .$$
But the dual $V^*\to U^*$ of the inclusion $U\to V$ is given by the restriction of  an element of $V^*$ (acting on $V$) to $U$. Now since the sequence is exact, we have
$$\ker(V^*\to U^*)\cong(V/U)^*,$$
and this kernel is tautologically $U^0$. Thus, the most natural statement is that
$$U^0\cong (V/U)^*,$$
and this becomes the statement that you want once again by the isomorphism of Hilbert spaces and their duals.

Comment: I understand that what I am talking about is utterly trivial, just wanted confirmation that at least my thinking is correct. Also why do you write $V\cong U\oplus U^\perp$ instead of simply $V=U\oplus U^\perp$? I understand that isomorphism means that they're essentially equal, but is it even necessary to use that? Isn't the direct sum defined in a way that allows for regular equality? Also, if you don't mind spelling it out for me, how exactly does $V\cong V^*$ imply $U^\perp\cong U^0$? Regarding your edit, I haven't yet met short exact sequences, so this is lost on me, but thank you anyway!

Comment: @V.Ch. I extended my answer with the way I believe to be more "correct" to think about the last statement. About writing $=$ or $\cong$, in the context of categories (e.g. here we are in the category of Hilbert spaces) we always write $\cong$. This indicates that there is a specified isomorphism that goes between the objects. It is important to keep track of these isomorphisms because e.g. sometimes you want to check that squares of morphisms commute or similar things.

Comment: I assume that you're familiar with linear/abstract algebra, would you mind recommending where to "go" after I'm done with Axler's book? For linear algebra I was thinking of trying Halmos' FDVS for the functional analysis perspective and, being interested in algebra in general, I thought to start reading Vinberg's "A Course in Algebra". Also I've heard that Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0" takes an interesting approach by introducing categories from the beginning. Anything you could recommend to someone interested in the subject of algebra in general?

Comment: @V.Ch. I don't have a good reference for linear algebra, I'm sorry. After having learned linear algebra, it very much depends which direction you want to go. Aluffi's book is good because it introduces you to categories (along with groups, representations, ...), which you will probably encounter a lot. After that, maybe Atiyah's commutative algebra if you want to look at algebraic geometry or if you're interested in commutative rings and modules. Otherwise in direction analysis after linear algebra you can pick up a book on functional analysis, for example (cont.)

Comment: @V.Ch. Functional analysis is essentially "infinite dimensional linear algebra" with a bit of topology mixed in and forms the basis for modern analysis (partial differential equations, Fourier analysis etc.) A third possibility could be looking at optimization theory, and you could go read Boyde & Vandenberghe (http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/). There's no right choice, it's just a matter of preferences, and I think it's a good idea to have basics of a bit of everything so you should probably go through all these possibilities (and more) during the years.

Comment: @V.Ch. The last sentence assuming you aim at doing research mathematics, of course. Otherwise it depends on your end goal!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I took the liberty of taking a look at your profile and it seemed to me that you're Swiss (or at least have studied there). Do you by any chance have any information regarding mathematical education in Germany, because if so, I would like to ask you a couple of questions, if possible of course.

P.S. I keep trying to add mentions but it just doesn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: @V.Ch. Yes, I am Swiss and I studied in Zurich (BSc and MSc, and then I did my PhD in France). Standard in Germany and Europe in general is ~3 years Bachelor, then Masters (about 2 years), and then a PhD (which can last anywhere from 3 to 6 years, average of 4 I would say, mostly country or even university specific). Note that it's not like e.g. in the US where you choose between a Masters or graduate school (which is essentially Masters + PhD). The majority of people go to industry after a Masters. Are there other things you would like to know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95693/discussion-between-v-ch-and-daniel-robert-nicoud).